# Ipython Notebook: Error in importing module

Tags: python, import, module, ipython

I am trying to import kabuki module. I installed the module in the terminal using easy_installation and everything seems in order. But when I import it in IPython notebook, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc-2.3.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pymc/flib.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc-2.3.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pymc/flib.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Can anyone help me and tell me how to fix this? I am using mac OS X.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-045d55581b72> in <module>()
----> 1 import kabuki

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kabuki-0.5.5-py2.7.egg/kabuki/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from hierarchical import *
      2 
      3 import utils
      4 import analyze
      5 import step_methods as steps

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kabuki-0.5.5-py2.7.egg/kabuki/hierarchical.py in <module>()
     11 
     12 import pandas as pd
---> 13 import pymc as pm
     14 import warnings
     15 

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc-2.3.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pymc/__init__.pyc in <module>()
     28 from .PyMCObjects import *
     29 from .InstantiationDecorators import *
---> 30 from .CommonDeterministics import *
     31 from .NumpyDeterministics import *
     32 from .distributions import *

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc-2.3.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pymc/CommonDeterministics.py in <module>()
     19 import inspect
     20 import types
---> 21 from .utils import safe_len, stukel_logit, stukel_invlogit, logit, invlogit, value, find_element
     22 from copy import copy
     23 import sys

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc-2.3.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pymc/utils.py in <module>()
     12 from copy import copy
     13 from .PyMCObjects import Variable
---> 14 from . import flib
     15 import pdb
     16 from numpy.linalg.linalg import LinAlgError
```

Also I am trying to import module hddm and it gives me the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-17365318b31c> in <module>()
----> 1 import hddm

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/HDDM-0.5.5-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/hddm/__init__.py in <module>()
      5 __version__ = '0.5.5'
      6 
----> 7 import likelihoods
      8 import generate
      9 import utils

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/HDDM-0.5.5-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/hddm/likelihoods.py in <module>()
      1 from __future__ import division
----> 2 import pymc as pm
      3 import numpy as np
      4 from scipy import stats
      5 

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc-2.3.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pymc/__init__.pyc in <module>()
     28 from .PyMCObjects import *
     29 from .InstantiationDecorators import *
---> 30 from .CommonDeterministics import *
     31 from .NumpyDeterministics import *
     32 from .distributions import *

/Applications/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymc-2.3.3-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg/pymc/CommonDeterministics.py in <module>()
     11 __docformat__ = 'reStructuredText'
     12 
---> 13 from . import PyMCObjects as pm
     14 from .Node import Variable
     15 from .Container import Container

ImportError: cannot import name PyMCObjects
```

Comment: "Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.3.dylib" is a clear hint what's wrong: you don't have the necessary gfortran library.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says and [the install documentation hinted](https://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc/INSTALL.html#dependencies), you need Fortran library if you compile PyMC from source. In this case, it's looking for [gfortran library](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinariesMacOS).

Comment: Given the path in the error message, I would suggest using Homebrew instead to install gfortran.

Comment: I'm having trouble with installing it using home-brew because the terminal always returns   -bash: brew: command not found

Comment: Thank you all! I was able to fix my problem using your solutions. I had to reinstall homebrew first and then installed fortran